# .NET: Output caching for WebMethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, outputcache

Can I have the return value of a WebMethod outputcached? E.g. if the WebMethod has been called in the last X seconds or minutes, don't actually run the method again--just use the same result as it last served. Or should I roll my own caching internally in the class/WebMethod?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [CacheDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.cacheduration%28VS.71%29.aspx) parameter of the WebMethod attribute to specify that the output of the request is cached for a given amount of time.

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration=60)]
```

The above code would make your webmethod cache its results for 60 seconds.